# Programming a powershell script to read emails from a CSV and then returning a CSV with Email addresses and GUid's

Tags: exchange-server, export-to-csv, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a script that should take in a CSV file which contains a list of Email addresses of old mailboxes on Exchange. I want to then search each address and return the corresponding Guid with each mail box into a CSV so I can keep a record when it comes to deleting mailboxes that have been backed up.

```
$UserAddresses = Import-Csv -Path “C:// File path”
$results = foreach ($address in $UserAddresses) {
    Get-MailboxDatabase |
        Get-MailboxStatistics |
        Where { $_.Identity -eq $address } |
        Select-Object DisplayName, MailboxGuid, Database
}

$results | Export-Csv C://ReturnedFilePath

Write-Output "Finished"
```

This code returns a blank CSV file.

Edit.

```
$UserAddresses = Import-CSV -Path C:/Temp/XXXXX
$counter

$results = Foreach ($address in $UserAddresses){
   $Email = $($address.EmailAddresses)
   Get-Mailbox -Identity $Email  | Select-Object Name,ExchangeGuid 
   $counter += 1

      if ($counter >= 5)
      {
          Write-output "Finished"
          continue
      }
```

}

```
$results | Export-CSV C:/Temp/ReportOfGuids.Csv
```

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong about your code, although I'd recommend avoiding typographic quotes in code just on general principle. Check that the pipeline inside your loop is actually producing the results you're expecting (by running just the first step, then first and second, and so on).

Comment: I managed to get it sorted after playing around with it some more.